# Creating static libraries and static linking with MSVC Build Tools on Windows

Tags: c, windows, msbuild, static-libraries, static-linking

My present goal is compiling, say, the SQLite library (C-language), statically linked with dependencies on Windows with MSVC Build Tools. I want to get a single DLL file, which may only depend on the core Windows/VC components, such as kernel32 or VC runtime. SQLite library has several extensions with external dependencies, for example, Zipfile/zlib or ICU/ICU. I want to enable these extensions with all necessary code statically linked in the sqlite3.dll file. I can compile it with dynamic linking just fine, but it requires separate dll dependency files, which is what I want to avoid.

Micorosoft has a basic tutorial [Walkthrough: Create and use a static library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-170), but I do not see clear instructions on how to do it from the MSVC Build Tools command line. My understanding is that to link a dependency statically, a static library file .lib is required. At the same time, import libraries also have the .lib extension.

I have several questions:

- How can I tell if a given .lib file is an import library or a static library? (I am interested in specific instructions, probably involving some command-line MS Build or Windows Resource Kit tools.)
- How do I create a static library vs. an import library from the command line given a single source file, say, SQLite3.c having no external dependencies?
- Is that correct that if all dependencies are provided as static libraries, the MS linker will create a statically linked dll automatically? (Say, I enable the Zipfile extension in SQLite, build a static zlib library according to instructions for the previous question, and provide it as a dependency to MS Build Tools linker.) Or are there special flags to request static linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after further exploration, it seems I have the answers.

The first question was asked here before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402586/know-if-lib-is-static-or-import/#6403559), and there is an interesting comment related to [libraries](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/25abf7cb-1384-4736-afb0-546caad0779c/#318cc880-6185-432c-ac31-ec361cd1ccc9) created with MinGW ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311621/) more relevant MinGW-related question). There are several options, and the simplest appears to be `lib /list sqlite3.lib`, which should list objects for a static library and produce no output for the import library.

The answer to the second question is given by [Misrosoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/managing-a-library?view=msvc-170), stating that
*The default mode for LIB is to build or modify a library of COFF objects. LIB runs in this mode when you do not specify /EXTRACT (to copy an object to a file) or /DEF (to build an import library).*

The third question was discussed before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556678/#10560101), and it appears that the answer is "yes". Come to think of it, a static library should contain the actual objects and no information about a DLL (which could have been created independently). The lib file is not good for use at run-time either way, so the only possibility for successful linking against static libraries should be the static mode.